# Separation of citations on two lists without packages

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I have to separate my citations on two lists: Preliminary Work (Own Papers) and the standard Bibliography list. The references to the standard Bibliography list should be numbered and cited with arabic numbers. The references to the Preliminary Work should be numbered and cited with roman numbers.

There are several packages, which do similar work. But it seems that none of them can be used in my case. For example, the package `multibib` introduces a nice tool for creating several citation lists and citing them with the user defined command like `\citesec`. However, this is not appropriate for my purposes (I can be wrong) since: (i) in the process of editing our document with co-authors we can move some items between different lists; (ii) we want to have a possibility to cite items from two lists as `\cite{Ref2, Own2}`, in order to get a result like [2, II]. It may also be important that these two lists should appear in different parts of the document.

In order to resolve this problem I define the new environment `thepreliminarywork` similar to the environment `thebibliography`. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{thepreliminarywork}[1]
     {\chapter*{Preliminary Work}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@Roman\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Roman\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thepreliminarywork' environment}}%
      \endlist}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

These are references to the standard bibliography list: \cite{Ref1}, \cite{Ref2}. This example works properly.

These are references to the list of preliminary papers: \cite{Own1}, \cite{Own2}. This example does not work properly since I want to get [I], [II].

I also want to write like this: \cite{Ref1, Own1}. This example also does not work properly since I want to get [1, I].   

\begin{thepreliminarywork}{9}
\bibitem{Own1} The preliminary paper no. 1.
\bibitem{Own2} The preliminary paper no. 2.
\end{thepreliminarywork}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Ref1} The paper no. 1.
\bibitem{Ref2} The paper no. 2.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This gives correct numbering in both lists of citations. However the result of citation with `\cite` is always given by arabic numbers. Is there a way to correct my code? Or maybe there are some completely alternative solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must redefine the internal command `\@bibitem` which is responsible for writing `\bibcite` command in the `.aux` file; we need that it writes `\theenumiv` and not `\the\value{enumiv}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thepreliminarywork}[1]
  {\chapter*{Preliminary Work}%
   \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{Preliminary work}}{\MakeUppercase{Preliminary work}}%
   %%% Redefine (locally) \@bibitem
   \def\@bibitem##1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
     {\string\bibcite{##1}{\csname the\@listctr\endcsname}}\fi\ignorespaces}%
   %%%
   \list{\@biblabel{\@Roman\c@enumiv}}%
     {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \@openbib@code
      \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \let\p@enumiv\@empty
      \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Roman\c@enumiv}}%
   \sloppy
   \clubpenalty4000
   \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
   \widowpenalty4000%
   \sfcode`\.\@m}
   {\def\@noitemerr
     {\@latex@warning{Empty `thepreliminarywork' environment}}%
    \endlist}
\makeatother
```

I've also changed the `\@mkboth` command to produce "Preliminary work" in the headers.

Comment: A (minor, nit-picky) suggestion: One might want to tell the user to call the `thepreliminarywork` environment with an argument such as `78` ("Roman": `LXXVIII`) rather than the "usual" value of `99` or `100` (which will get rendered much more compactly as `IC` and `C`...) to make LaTeX set aside enough space for (Roman-numbered) labels, or one could use the value of `78` as the default value for the calculation of the `\labelwidth` calculation. :-)

Comment: @Mico Of course you're right; I'd suggest to wait until the list of "preliminary work" items is in final form and to look at the widest label.